# apex repeat not working in content type doc

Tags: apex, visualforce, repeat, renderas

The Output works fine in PDF, but not in Word, Apex:Repeat is not rendering the contacts in a word document. Could someone give me suggestions as to why it is not working?

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" standardStylesheets="false" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" contentType="application/msword#SalesforceCat.doc" >

    <!-- styles -->

    <body>
        <img src='https://c.na15.content.force.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=015i0000008RMYR&oid=00Di0000000hz1j&lastMod=1443192829000' title="logo"/>
        <h4> This is an example of table styles.</h4>
        <table width="100%" class="table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
            <th> Name</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <apex:repeat value="{!Account.Contacts}" var="con">
                    <tr>
                        <td>{!con.Name}</td>
                        <td>{!con.FirstName}</td>
                    </tr>
                </apex:repeat>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: are you able to see the logo in the document?

Comment: @SantanuBoral: No, Logo is also not coming up. however major issue is with Contacts.

Comment: without the logo document is showing contacts. your code is rendering contacts properly at my DE. Are you correctly passing the AccountId in the URL which has contacts?

Comment: @Yes. For some reason it is started working. Thank you.

Comment: close your own question